# Collection Sort method not working properly on linked list

Tags: java, sorting, collections, linked-list

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.*;
public class ListMerge<String> extends LinkedList<String>
{
    public LinkedList<String> mergeLists(LinkedList<String> one, LinkedList<String> two)
    {
        LinkedList<String> newList = new LinkedList<String>(); 
        newList.addAll(one); 
        newList.addAll(two); 
        newList = Collections.sort(newList); 

        return newList; 
    }  
}
```

I get the error "cannot find symbol - method sort(java.util.LinkedList), and I am completely unaware as to why it is not working. I've imported the collections class and in the in-line coding I've called Collections, so I'm not sure why it can't seem to find the method.

I'm a beginner in coding so my vocabulary in coding isn't too strong, so please accommodate!

Thank you!

Comment: `Collection` and `Collections` are two different classes.

Comment: You're completely right Sotirios! I did not notice that; however, when I changed the method names, it's the same error.

Comment: No, it's a different error. The generic parameter you've declared in `ListMerge<String>` is shadowing the type `String`.

Comment: so how might I go about fixing this issue? sorry, i'm just not getting it

Comment: I don't want to give you the answer. Maybe others will. Go through [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) to understand the syntax of a Generic class declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Watch out for return type: [`void sort(List<T> list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29), it sorts given list.

Compiler expects method with signature `LinkedList<String> sort(List<T> list)`, which is not exist in `Collections` class.

This line is illegal:

```
newList = Collections.sort(newList);
```

You could easily fix that:

```
 Collections.sort(newList);
```

Comment: you are perfectly right. I should have checked. Thanks for your time! much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you're intending on extending LinkedList, you have to extend the generic class "LinkedList... you can't extend a version of a generic class with the type specified: "LinkedList".  You only specify a generic class's template arguments "with String, for instance" when you instantiate an instance of it

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>()
```

You might find it simpler, however, to have a ListMerger class, that has a method "mergeLists" which returns a LinkedList object.

```
public class ListMerger<E extends Comparable>
{
    public LinkedList<E> mergeLists(LinkedList<E> one, LinkedList<E> two)
    {
        LinkedList<E> newList = new LinkedList<E>(); 
        newList.addAll(one); 
        newList.addAll(two); 
        Collections.sort(newList);

        return newList; 
    }  
}
```

And as others have mentioned, yes, the Collections.sort method modifies the list you input.  It doesn't return a sorted copy of it.  So see how I did it in my code. Then, all you have to do to get your merged LinkedList is this:

```
ListMerger<String> merger = new ListMerger<String>();
LinkedList<String> mergedList = merger.mergeLists(one, two);
```

Notice how I specified "String" when I was USING the generic class.  Not defining it.  Oh, and notice I changed the name from ListMerge to ListMerger.  Just personal preference I guess.

EDIT: Updated the example to require E to be "Comparable".  That way, Collections.sort() will accept it.

Comment: thank you so much! I should have checked the return type of the method.

Comment: Just a heads up.. I'm a bit foggy on syntax.  E needs to be "bounded" so it is restricted to only classes that implement "Comparable".  Will update if I get the chance.  Or, you could have ListMerger not be generic, and only accept LinkedList<String> arguments.  Then you don't have to worry about templates.  Maybe name the thing StringListMerger.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue after changing to `java.util.Collections` is the following

```
                                                  v this is a type argument
public class ListMerge<String> extends LinkedList<String>
                       ^ this is a type parameter
```

The type parameter you have in `ListMerge<String>`, ie. `<String>` is the simple name of the parameter. It has nothing to do with `java.lang.String`. As such [you are obscuring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2) the type `java.lang.String`.

This might actually be what you wanted in the first place, ie. you planned to have `ListMerge` work for all types, equivalent to

```
public class ListMerge<T> extends LinkedList<T>
```

If it isn't, then what you want is

```
public class ListMerge extends LinkedList<String>
```

Go through the [official Java generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) to understand more about the syntax of generic class declarations.